# In standard orthic configuration , find AB + AC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]
Consider standard orthic configuration notation.

$\angle FA'E=30$
$\angle BAD : \angle CAD = 2 : 3$ . Given $~BD$ = 3 , find $~AB + AC $.

Comment: i cant see the how $\angle FA^{'}E = 30^\circ$ helps.

Comment: @abel $\, A'$ is the midpoint of $BC$. He forgot to say that. That's why $AB = 6$ and $BC = 3\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: @Futurologist how did u get $\angle BAD = \angle FA'E$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\angle BFC = \angle BEC = 90^{\circ}$, $BFEC$ is cyclic and the center of their circle is $A'$. Thus, from $\angle FA'E = 30^{\circ}$, $\angle FBE = \angle FCE = 15^{\circ}$ follows.

If $\angle BAD = 2\varphi$ and $\angle CAD = 3\varphi$, then $\angle BAC = 5\varphi$. From the right triangle $BAE$ $5\alpha = 75^{\circ}$ and $\alpha=15^{\circ}$. So $\angle BAD = 30^{\circ}$, $\angle CAD = 45^{\circ}$.

Now from $BD=3$ $AB=6$ follows. Thus $AD=3\sqrt{3}$ and $AC=3\sqrt{6}$.